# what is @params inside comments? and how to enable the dropdown menu for those in IDE 7.0 for PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, comments

i found that, commenting by describing the function using @desc, @params, etc is good practice, but what this process is called and how to enable the dropdown menu for this feature in IDE 7.0, I when i write @ and hit control+space, it says no suggestion, any idea? how to enable it? i had seen someone using it in one video.

Comment: please show an example of how you use this

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#DocBlock

Comment: [It's `@param` not `@params`](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/tags/param.html). `@desc` does not exist.

Comment: still, after @, no suggestion found is giving.

Comment: i mean to say, 
<pre>/**
*<br>
*@param description of a parameter<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*/</pre>
still after pressing @, hint doesnt shows up...

Comment: the tags are not being shown in my netbeans ide 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are starting the commented section with /* instead of /**. If you only do one * for some reason auto complete doesn't show up. At least that is the case with 7.2, I don't have 7.0 installed.